# Tooltip not working in thread

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety

I want to show tooltips in a thread here is a code I write its work fine without thread

```
private sub button_click(sender as object,e As eventargs)

Dim th As New Thread(Addressof test)
th.start()

' tooltip.show('test',label1,1000) <--- this line work fine if i uncomment

End Sub

sub test()
tooltip.show('test',label1,1000)
End sub
```

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? A tool tip is part of the UI. Why are you trying to manipulate the UI on any thread other than the UI thread? It's called the UI thread for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not work with UI controls from other thread, than thread which they were created on. That is rule in all languages and all operating systems.

You must invoke that on correct thread:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim th As New Thread(AddressOf test)
  th.Start()
End Sub
Sub test()
  BeginInvoke(Sub()
                ToolTip1.Show("test", Label1, 1000)
              End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is rather important to check the [**`InvokeRequired` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) as well since invoking _when it isn't needed_ is a waste of resources and causes extra overhead.

Comment: This answer really needs to have some explanation as to what circumstances that invoking immediately back to the UI thread is useful. Otherwise this approach is a complete waste of time and resources. In other words, why not just show the tooltip on the click event and avoid creating a new thread.

Comment: I did not use InvokeRequired because I wanted this as simple as possible. And more stuff would just confuse OP. Everything regarding to why is it that way is explained - as simple as possible too.

Comment: @Ondřej - Yes, but why start a new thread and then immediately invoke back to the UI? Why not just show the tool tip without starting a new thread? This is a wasteful answer unless there's a reason why a new thread is useful.

Comment: @Enigmativity WHY is not subject of this question. HOW is important. (Yes it can be completely useless)

Comment: @Ondřej - It's always worthwhile trying to explain the pitfalls. This answer is a way how to do this, but it's not a good way - in fact this is a bad way. A disclaimer explaining that you're only doing it this way because the OP asked would be useful for future readers. I've been on SO long enough to know what should and shouldn't be in an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity SO long enough and still only thing you have done was bitching about my answer...

Comment: @Ondřej - I'm not bitching - I'm trying to help improve the quality of this answer. That's one of the main roles of the community here.